# Significato di "lesse" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto questa frase:

> Il marinaio **lesse**, e sorrise, con ironica commiserazione.

Il verbo "leggere" è usato così, in modo assoluto, senza che ci sia nel testo, ne prima ne dopo di questa frase, nessun riferimento a qualche scritto o altri segni da interpretare. Questo mi rende difficile capire il suo senso: ho cercato questo verbo in alcuni dizionari, ma non mi è stato di aiuto. Nel paragrafo precedente a questa frase vengono spiegati i pensieri del barone di Mandralisca che è accanto a questo marinaio. Ho pensato che potesse significare che, in certo modo, il marinaio lesse nella mente del barone e capì a cosa stava pensando, ma non sono sicura che questa sia l'interpretazione corretta. Cosa ne pensate?
Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire?

**Aggiornamento:**

Ecco i due paragrafi precedenti alla frase sopra citata:

> E qui sorrise, amaro e subito ironico, scorgendo stupore e pena sul volto del barone. Il quale, pur seguendo il discorso del marinaio, da 
>   un po' di tempo si chiedeva dove mai aveva visto quell'uomo e quando. Ne era certo, non era la prima volta che l'incontrava, ci avrebbe scommesso il fondo di Colombo o il cratere del *Venditore di tonno*
>   della sua raccolta. Ma *dove* l'aveva visto? 
>         Ma sotto lo sguardo dell'uomo, acuto e scrutatore, ritornò con la mente al cavatore. Al di là di Canneto, verso il ponente, s'erge dal mare un monte bianco, abbagliante che chiamasi Pelato. Quivi copiosa schiera d'uomini, brulichìo nero di tarantole e scarafaggi, sotto un sole di foco che pare di Marocco, gratta la pietra porosa col piccone; curva sotto le ceste esce da buche, da grotte, gallerie; scivola sopra pontili esili di tavole che s'allungano nel mare fino ai velieri. Sotto queste immagini il Mandralisca cercava di nascondere, di rimandare indietro altre che in quel momento (frecce di volatili nel cielo di tempesta migranti verso l'Africa, verdi chiocciole segnanti sulla pietra strie d'argento, alte flessuose palme schiudenti le vulve delle spate con le bianche pasquali inflorescenze...), chissà per quale associazione o contrappunto, premevano per affiorare in primo piano. E quindi si presentarono, con disappunto del barone, davanti a quell'uomo indagatore e giudice, ordinate nei loro volumi, con titolo e stamperia e anno d'edizione, nella forma degli studi di cui il barone, in altri momenti, intimamente si compiaceva, con un certo orgoglio, con una certa soddisfazione, studi che gli avevano aperto le porte delle più importanti Accademie del Regno, Gioenia Peloritana Zelanti Pellegrini: *Catalogo degli uccelli che si trovano stazionarî o di passaggio nelle isole Eolie, Catalogo dei molluschi terrestri e fluviatili delle Madonie e luoghi adiacenti, Catalogo e fecondazione delle palme*.

Comment: Puoi aggiungere qualche altra frase per contestualizzare meglio la situazione? Potrebbe significare il marinaio lesse (nello sguardo), e sorrise

Comment: @abarisone: Lo faccio subito.

Comment: Non sono sicuro di aver capito bene: subito prima della frase col marinaio che lesse c'è quell'elenco di titoli? E allora chiaramente si riferisce a quello: il marinaio lesse i titoli e compatì, immagino, lo sfoggio di erudizione e bibliofilia del barone.

Comment: @DaG: Forse sono io che non ho capito nulla, ma avevo interpretato che questi titoli si presentarono nella mente del barone di Mandralisca e facevano parte di queste "immagini" che "il Mandralisca cercava di nascondere, di rimandare indietro" ritornando "con la mente al cavatore", e che "chissà per quale associazione o contrappunto, premevano per affiorare in primo piano". Avevo interpretato che tutto questo accadeva nella mente del barone.

Comment: Rispondo qui, ma mi rivolgo anche ad @abarisone. Charo, il marinaio è anche quello che “sorrise, amaro e subito ironico”, nonché l'“uomo, acuto e scrutatore”? Se sì, parrebbe una situazione un po' onirica in cui il barone passa in rassegna certe immagini e ricordi, e il marinaio è in grado di vederli a sua volta, fino a leggere i titoli dei libri che per il barone sono motivo d'orgoglio, mentre nell'altro ispirano commiserazione. Può essere?

Comment: @DaG Sinceramente ora sono anch'io piuttosto confuso. Il testo si presta a più interpretazioni, anche se penso che comunque possa valere il mio ultimo commento alla risposta.

Comment: @DaG: Effettivamente, il marinaio è quello che “sorrise, amaro e subito ironico”, nonché l'“uomo, acuto e scrutatore”. Non credo si tratti di una situazione onirica, ma penso che si cerchi di descrivere quello che passava per la mente di quei due personaggi.

Comment: @abarisone: Siccome sono d'accordo con te, per me va benissimo se metti tutte e due le interpretazioni nella risposta.

Comment: @Charo Modificata la risposta

Comment: Quello che mi fa pensare che, in qualche senso, il marinaio “veda” i pensieri del barone è questa concatenazione di frasi: “Sotto queste immagini il Mandralisca cercava di nascondere ... altre ... E quindi si presentarono ... davanti a quell'uomo indagatore e giudice, ordinate nei loro volumi”, come se appunto il barone non fosse in grado di celare i propri pensieri al suo interlocutore.

Comment: @DaG: Questo è più o meno quello che avevo interpretato io, ma non ne ero sicura e perciò ho posto la domanda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il passaggio da te citato si presta a più interpretazioni:

Se tutto ciò che accade avviene nella mente del barone allora leggere è figurato e quindi il marinaio ***lesse*** lo sguardo, l'espressione del barone riuscendo in qualche modo a intuire i pensieri che si susseguivano nella sua testa.

Oltre lo sguardo si può, ad esempio, anche leggere una situazione cioè capire in anticipo come stanno le cose in determinate circostanze.

Invece, se i libri erano fisicamente sulla scena allora significa proprio che il marinaio effettivamente ***lesse*** i titoli dei volumi su cui aveva studiato il barone e poi sorrise con ironica commiserazione, compatendo il suo sfoggio di erudizione e bibliofilia.

Comment: Direi proprio che si riferisca ai titoli elencati, no? Vedi il mio commento alla domanda.

Comment: @DaG Leggendo più attentamente il passaggio penso che abbia senso il tuo ragionamento. Provvedo a modificare la risposta, dato che quella attuale era figlia del mio commento iniziale.

Comment: Certo, senza il capoverso sui libri poteva essere.

Comment: Beh... se è così, è che non avevo capito proprio nulla.

Comment: Se tutto ciò che accade avviene nella mente del barone allora avrebbe senso la mia prima risposta dove leggere è figurato, altrimenti se effettivamente il marinaio legge i titoli dei volumi quella attuale. Secondo me la parte che immagina il barone inizia con _Al di là..._ e termina con _...premevano per affiorare in primo piano._ Che ne pensi @DaG?

Comment: @abarisone:  Inoltre, in quel momento sono sulla coperta di un battello di ritorno da Lipari a Cefalù e non capisco perché dovrebbero apparire tutti questi libri (dovete sapere che Consolo ha un gusto speciale per fare elenchi di cose).

Comment: @abarisone: Non credo che la prima interpretazione (che mi sembra la più plausibile) corrisponda necessariamente a una situazione onirica: semplicemente il marinaio intuisce i pensieri del barone, mentre nella seconda i libri appaiono letteralmente sulla scena.

Comment: Risposta rielaborata